# Nginx redirect www to non www while maintaining wildcard ability

Tags: nginx, web, redirect

Trying to redirect www to non www while still maintaining the wildcard ability for a multi tenant white label architecture. Any help would be great thanks.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name .domain.com;

  …
}
```

Comment: If you want to do everything in the same server block, try adding: `if ($http_host ~* ^www\.(.*)$) { return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri; }`